# retrieving duplicate records through sql

Tags: sql

I have a data like

```
paper Id Author Id  

1          15
2          13 
3          12
3          11 
4          10
4          10
4          9
```

I want to select papers having multiple authors.So my data should look like

```
paper Id   Author Id
3            12
3            11
4            10
4             9
```

I tried with sql query :

```
statement<-"SELECT PaperId,AuthorId,COUNT(PaperId) 
            FROM author_data_pap_aut
            GROUP BY PaperId,AuthorId
            HAVING ( COUNT(*) >1 )"
```

But its not working.How can i get the desired result

Thanks

Comment: "*its not working*" is not an acceptable error description. And please add a tag for the DBMS you are using (Postgres, Oracle, ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT PaperId 
FROM author_data_pap_aut
GROUP BY PaperId
HAVING COUNT(distinct AuthorId) > 1
```

And if you need the authors too then use

```
select distinct PaperId, AuthorId
from author_data_pap_aut
where PaperId in
(
    SELECT PaperId 
    FROM author_data_pap_aut
    GROUP BY PaperId
    HAVING COUNT(distinct AuthorId) > 1
)
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to use `group_concat()` function for do your process